# Mac .app file no longer working after being served by a webserver

Tags: macos, flash, .app

Ok, so I am having a small problem. I have an .app file that was created by the Adobe Air converter. It works fine. However, when the .app file is zipped up on a CENT OS server the app no longer works. You can double click on the icon but the app just never launches.

The only weird thing that is being done by the server is that it is editing an xml file within the .app package, however, this .xml file doesn't even get loaded by the app until after it has launched so I can't see this being an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I bet you (or the Adobe Air converter you used) code-signed your app package, in which case modifying the XML file (after it being built) would break things.  I work on an app which requires frequent customization like this and the only way we're getting around it is to use a Macintosh (a MacMini) that's dedicated to building and code-signing unique versions.

The way to know what's going on is to look at your "`Console.app`" log, which should be logging some kind of error when you double click on your downloaded app.

Another thing you can do is (temporarily) ***disable*** the code on the web server that modifies the XML file and see if the downloaded app magically starts to work.

Comment: hmm interesting. The error being printed to the console is:

Job Failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 13
No information from LS about running process

Comment: Also I think i might have found what is causing the problem. In Contents/MacOS of the .app the executable is displaying as a "document" instead of a "unix executable file", although I have no idea how to fix this :S